# Angular2 (with postcss/Sass) log CSS changes from DevTools

Tags: css, logging, angular, google-chrome-devtools

While developing, despite live-reload and everything, I usually use DevTools to test the css code to apply.

Problem is, that the changes I apply are only temporary, and saving them directly to the original files with PostCSS and SASS is hard, add Angular2 and ShadowDom and I can't even find the css source file in the Source tab, figure saving in the original source scss file… Any way it would not be what I want, which is simply to log the changes I make, like for example:

```
p {
  […]
  - font-size: 1rem;
  + font-size: 1.5rem;
  […]
}
li {
  - color: #FFF;
  + color: #000;
}
```

Expecially thanks to the extremely annoying WebStorm's "feature" of automatically saving files every time you go out of its scope I can't tell how many times I found a solution in DevTools and then lost it when I forgot a single detail and I get mad trying to figure out what I did to manage to make it work. Also because the changes might have been applied to several elements, and I might forget to have changed one.

I tried to go through all the Chrome's extensions and I only find answers dated to 2012 suggesting to use DevTool's Source tab, that apparently doesn't even work with Angular2 and ShadowDom.

Anybody knows a solution?